# Trouble installing Ubuntu 12.10 on Macbook Pro

Tags: installation, 12.10, boot, macbook

i converted the `ISO` file into a `IMG` image. Made the Bootable Drive, restart and choose to boot from drive.

When it boots from the drive, I get `secure boot not enabled`.

Then I get *try Ubuntu* and *install Ubuntu*, drive appears to be working, but when I choose either one of the options I get a black screen but nothing happens, any help with this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! In [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) you will find all the necessary information to (try to) solve your problem. If that doesn't fully address your problem, you should tell us. Thanks!